# woocommerce webhooks not firing

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, woocommerce

woocommerce webhooks aren't firing at all for me, even on a fresh install.  I did the following:

1. Create a new MySQL database
2. Install WP from the zip file.
3. Set up WP.
4. Install Woocommerce.
5. Enable REST API and create a key.
6. Added "Coupon created" webhook, made sure it's set to active, and set it to a publicly accessible site.

When I create a coupon, the webhook does not fire, and no entry is created in the log.  I tried this with orders as well and also doesn't work.

I think it's a machine configuration problem, but not sure what to change.  The machine is an EC2 instance and has all ports opened in its security group policy.

Weirdest of all is that on a different EC2 instance does work, but it's a production machine and I want to have a dev server work so I can test out things.  The only config differences between the production and dev machines that I can think of are the subnets and the firewall, but I don't understand why the subnet should matter and I opened all the firewall ports on the dev machine.

Comment: is MySQL running on the same EC2 instance or do you use RDS service ?

Answer (score 0):

what Linux distributions are you running for prod and dev?

CentOS with SELinux enabled with not allow HTTPD scripts and modules to connect to network by default.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

If above is not valid, please identify network problems by trying connecting to AWS RDS via SSH CLI. If you can open a connection via SSH CLI, the problem will be with your application. If you can't, it will be network problem. First thing to check in that case is AWS RDS security group. For testing you can open 3306 to public.

Let me know how it goes.